# I want to access the gpt-3.5 version and its model to solve my problem

Tags: model, openai-api, gpt-3, mlmodel

I'm running my code in annaconda spyder(Windows) and getting "InvalidRequestError: This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?" error. Have tried inserting env variable in spyder.

` from openai import OpenAI

def generate_synonyms(word):

```
client = OpenAI()

prompt = f"Can you provide synonyms for the word '{word}'?"

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "I'm an assistant capable of providing information on various topics."},
        {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
    ]
)

return completion.choices[0].message
```

word = "battery"

synonyms = generate_synonyms(word)

print("Synonyms for the word", word + ":", synonyms)`

This is my code.